# Load external site in div on click on related tabs

Tags: ajax, jquery, load

i am trying to load external sites in a div on clicking to the respective tabs. i am new to ajax jquery cud any one can suggest for correct solution.

[i have tried this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ztxsx/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this using an iframe due to cross domain restrictions. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

To get around this you can change the #test element to be an iframe
and rather than ajax loading try something like:

```
$("#test").prop("src", link);
```

I've updated your fiddle to show a working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ztxsx/5/

Essentially all you need Javascript wise is:

```
$('#nav ul li a').on("click", function(e) {

    var url =  $(this).text();
    var li_link ='http://www.' + url + '.com';
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#test").prop("src", li_link);       
});
```

​

Comment: hi Dave your code works fine its working, but one question why  google,yahoo,youtube sites are not opening?

Comment: Because Google explicitly denies the request using these HTTP headers

x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block